# Linking error using 'idf.py build' on esp32s2

Tags: c, esp32

I am trying out a very simple case on my esp32s2. The build seems ok, but the linking not so much.

The aim of the code is to send a keystroke (esp32s2 as a USB device). It is as following:

```
#include "tinyusb.h"
#include "class/hid/hid_device.h"
#include "tusb.h"

enum {
ITF_KEYBOARD = 1,
ITF_MOUSE = 0
};

void app_main(void)
{
tusb_init();
tud_task(); // tinyusb device task

uint8_t keycode[6] = { 0 };
keycode[0] = 0x04 ; //HID_KEY_A;
tud_hid_n_keyboard_report(ITF_KEYBOARD, 0, 0, keycode);
}
```

The CMakeLists.txt inside the main folder is like:

```
idf_component_register(SRCS main.c
INCLUDE_DIRS ".")
```

The CMakeLists.txt ouside the main folder is like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(test)
```

And the makefile is like:

```
PROJECT_NAME := project_name

include $(IDF_PATH)/make/project.mk
```

I also tryed to copy the lib hid_device.c/h inside my project, it works well, but the linking still not work.

When I build the project, I got the following error:

```
[ 99%] Linking C static library libmain.a
[ 99%] Built target __idf_main
[ 99%] Generating ld/sections.ld
[ 99%] Built target __ldgen_output_sections.ld
[ 99%] Linking CXX executable test.elf
/home/me/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32s2-elf/esp-2021r2-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32s2-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32s2-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32s2-elf/bin/ld: esp-idf/main/libmain.a(main.c.obj):(.literal.app_main+0x0): undefined reference to `tud_hid_n_keyboard_report'
/home/me/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32s2-elf/esp-2021r2-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32s2-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32s2-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32s2-elf/bin/ld: esp-idf/main/libmain.a(main.c.obj): in function `app_main':
/home/me/My_project/project_test_HID/main/main.c:37: undefined reference to `tud_hid_n_keyboard_report'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.elf.dir/build.make:538 : test.elf] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2458 : CMakeFiles/test.elf.dir/all] Erreur 2
make: *** [Makefile:149 : all] Erreur 2
make failed with exit code 2
```

If you have any idea, please let me know :)

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You're including headers from an ESP-IDF component called "tinyusb" (that's the name of the directory in [its source code](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/components): `esp-idf/components/tinyusb`). But if you're using a component, you must tell the build system about this - otherwise it will not pull in the implementation of this component and you get linker errors.

You can pull it in via your main CMakeLists.txt like so:

```
idf_component_register(SRCS main.c
INCLUDE_DIRS "."
REQUIRES "tinyusb")
```

It's all explained more or less clearly in the [ESP IDF build system documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#component-cmakelists-files)

Comment: OMG ! Thank you !!!

Comment: Well the error is still there though
```
undefined reference to `tud_hid_n_keyboard_report'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```
At first I thought the issue was solved but I didn't uncoment the code argh

Comment: OK, then you might want to run `idf.py menuconfig` and enable TinyUSB and its relevant options under submenu "Components"

Comment: I already did that on a sdkconfig file.

I think the issue is form the linking part. I guess ld doesn't find the libraries. I don't figure out how to set the correct value inside the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I think I cannot even know how to import that lib: hid_device.h which appears to be a subcomponent of the tinyusb component.

Comment: I don't think you'll have much success bypassing the build system. The intended usage is to pull in the component in your main CMakeLists.txt and configure it in menuconfig so relevant code gets enabled (e.g. `#if (TUSB_OPT_DEVICE_ENABLED && CFG_TUD_HID)` in `hid_device.c`).

Comment: I'd love to activate the code in configmenu, but I TUSB_OPT_DEVICE_ENABLED and CFG_TUD_HID are not in sdkconfig. So maybe they are listed under another name. But how to figure out? The usb module is  pretty interesting, but I don't get why there is not so much documentation about it. If you know the relevant options in menuconfig, please let me know :)

Comment: You can search configuration defines inside `menuconfig` with by typing `/`, then "guessing" the stuff you're interested in. E.g. `USB`. If you see results, you can navigate to them. In general, if you need more information about one component, you can use `?` to display more information, in particular also dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Using `menuconfig` under `Component config > TinyUSB Stack > Human Interface Device Class (HID)`, setting `TINYUSB_HID_COUNT` to a value greater than 0 will enable TinyUSB HID.